# How to extract word between number and a comma in a string

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, text-extraction

How do I extract "Seri Kembangan" in googlesheet?

Farm In The City, Lot 40187-40188, Jalan Tropika Barat 1, Pusat Bandar Putra
Permai, 43300 Seri Kembangan, Selangor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\d+ (.+),")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain why it did not include the postcode in the extract?

Comment: @FH sure, regex means: extract everything `.+` which is between `(.+)` number `\d+` foflowed by space ` ` and comma `,`. if you want to extract 43300 too you can use: `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(\d+ .+),")`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=regexextract(A1,"\d\ (.*),")
```